# Is there any option in Visual Studio 2015 like -std in GCC?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

The default setting for VS2015 is C++14. I wonder is there any option I can tweak to set the C++ standard which the compiler uses? Something like `-std=c++11` in g++?

Comment: at least from Googling and my experience: No. You can install an older VC++ version (eg. 2013) and set the platform toolset to Visual C++ 2013 in the project settings

Comment: Not an option.  MSFT had to completely rewrite their front-end to make it C++1x compatible.  Features were phased-in gradually, starting at VS2010 and not completed for C++11 until VS2015.  The _MSC_VER macro is the clunky alternative.